# What are E-modules from the point of view of derived algebraic geometry?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, partial-differential-equations, homological-algebra, higher-category-theory, d-modules

For a complex manifold $X$, there exists a ring of formal differential operators on $T^* M$, normally denoted as $\mathscr{E}_X$. Locally, a section of $\mathscr{E}_X$ is given by a formal sum
$$P = \sum_{-\infty \leq j \leq m} p_j$$
where $p_j \in \mathcal{O}_{T^* X}(j)$, holomorphic functions on $T^* X$ of degree $j$ on the cotangent direction, satisfying certain growth conditions, and its product is dictated by how principal symbols multiply. (For details, see for example Schapira's [book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-61665-5).) One main property of $\mathscr{E}_X$ is the it microlocalizes $\mathscr{D}_X$ in the sense that $\pi^{-1}\mathscr{D}_X \hookrightarrow \mathscr{E}_X$ is faithfully flat.

Now, in the algebraic setting, $\mathscr{D}_X$-modules can be identified with (quasi/in)-coherent sheaves on the De Rham space $X_{dR}$ where $X$ is a smooth scheme as discussed in Gaitsgory and Rozenblyum's [book](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Egaitsgde/GL/crystext.pdf). (It might be true for the analytic setting, in some correct sense, but I do not know a reference.)

My question is if there is an interpretation of $\mathscr{E}_X$-modules as some version of coherent sheaves on some stack naturally associated to $X$ in either the algebraic or analytic setting? And if so, is there a reference?

Comment: I don't know if  this link is of help: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10556/d-modules-derham-spaces-and-microlocalization.